# A counterexample for the claim that "$d(0,x+y)\le d(0,x) + d(0,y)$ for any metric $d$"?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

The question is

> Is $d(0,x+y)\le d(0,x) + d(0,y)$ for any metric $d$ defined on a vector space?

This is clearly true for a norm-induced metric.

However, I don't think it is true in general. Anyone can help think of a counterexample? The answer to this question would also serve as a counterexample that not all metric is norm-induced. Thank you!

Comment: You have to specify your question since you are assuming the existence of the operation $+$. Anyway, for a vector space counterexample, take d(x,y)=|e^x - e^y| for each $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no restrictions on what $d$ can do besides that $d$ be a metric, then the answer is indeed. no.

Fix two distinct points $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and consider the metric $d$ given by:

- $d(x, x)=0$,
- $d(\alpha,\beta)=d(\beta, \alpha)=1$, and
- $d(x, y)=3$ if $x\not=y$ and $\{x, y\}\not=\{\alpha,\beta\}$.

It's not hard to see that this is indeed a metric, albeit a very silly one; and if we take $\alpha=0$ and $\beta$ be any nonzero point, we get $$d(0, \beta+\beta)=3>1+1=d(0, \beta)+d(0, \beta).$$